# Ordering in VAR models

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

In Enders' 'Applied Econometric Time Series', I repeatedly stumbled upon the notion of the "ordering of a VAR model" and I am not sure I understand the concept right. As far as I understand it, the concept relates to the problem of recovering the true $\epsilon$ of the underlying structural equations.

Looking e.g. at the following VAR in standard form:

$y_t = a_{10} + a_{11}y_{t-1} + a_{12}z_{t-1} + e_{1t}$

$z_t = a_{20} + a_{21}y_{t-1} + a_{22}z_{t-1} + e_{2t}$

The problem is that the two errors are actually composites of the underlying shocks $\epsilon_{yt}$ and $\epsilon_{zt}$ of the structural equations, which we do not know. Here, Enders mentions that "(...) if the correlation coefficient between the $e_{1t}$ and $e_{2t}$ is low, the ordering is not likely to be important", and vice versa.

My problem is that I do not grasp the concept of ordering and how it would affect the identification problem of the disturbances in the structural model. Does ordering refer to the order of the independent variables in the VAR?

Comment: It seems that with "ordering", Enders refers to the ordering of the Choleski decomposition, meaning that whether $b_{12}$ or $b_{21}$ are set equal to zero to restrict the VAR model and consequently identify the underlying model in structural for. Maybe someone can confirm/clarify this for me?

Comment: Here is a tutorial that can help you! https://youtu.be/SbE8ns0oOTs Regards!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will try to answer your second part of the question. If you understand this, I hope you will be able to answer the first part.

Ordering means placing the variables (all) in the decreasing order of exogenity . For example, if `y1,y2, and y3` are three variables in the system and if we have from economic theory (or previous empirical findings) that `y2` is relatively more exogeneous than `y1` and `y3` and `y1` is relatively more exogeneous than `y3` but less exogenous than `y2`, then we have the order as `y2 y1 y3`. To put in simple words, `y2` (say weather) is more likely to influence `y1` (GDP) and `y3` (traveling) but the reverse is not true and `y1 (GDP)` is more likely to influence `y3` (traveling) but the reverse is not true.Note that we are talking here of `relative exogenity` not the absolute one.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, ordering the variables by exogeneity, i.e. causal priority will change the order of the coefficients in $B^{-1}$ matrix and, hence, the Choleski decomposition. We thereby attach economic meaning to our choice of restriction.
The order of the dependent variables is then of course only an issue when $n>2$ and the correlation coefficient between the variables is high enough.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. According to the Enders, the cut-off limit for (where the ordering doesn't have any influence) the off-diagonal element of the variance-covariance matrix is 0.2. Yes,it changes the decomposition. However, I am not sure whether it only holds for n>2.

Comment: Well, my thought was that when $n=2$, $B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & b_{12}\\ b_{21} & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and I can let $b_{12}=0$ or $b_{21}=0$ without changing the ordering, but by simply changing the Choleski decomposition.

Comment: That makes sense.